# Laptop heats up while using ubuntu

Tags: laptop

Don't Know why my PC heats up while i use ubuntu (any version). I have dell i7 processor system with 1 GB nvidia. Still finding solution but no positive and effective solution found. any suggestion

Comment: Usually computers heat up, when they have some occupying job to do for a long time. Be it processor job or graphical job. Start by examining what's running on your processor. Run "System monitor", and click on "% CPU" column. This will show you processes sorted by how they use CPU. Alternatively, you could run ps aux | sort -rk 3,3 |head in the terminal. This will be easier to copy :) Please report those, and we can work from there.

Comment: You might also want to investigate using tlp to help limit power consumption (heat generation).  The link for the ppa to install tlp is on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/tlp)

Comment: If it gets this warm without any activity (CPU/GPU usage), then something is seriously wrong and maybe even a fan is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The red colour in pSensor can be changed to anything you want so that is not a problem.

### If you've got old hardware:

(larger number = more difficult)

1. Put a 1" (2.5cm) thick book under the backside of your laptop so that is inclines towards you and heat can better radiate away.
2. Take your vacuum cleaner, put it on its nearly lowest setting and vacuum all over the laptop.  If your vacuum cleaner power cannot be changed, skip to next item
3. Close the laptop firmly, put the vacuum cleaner on 500W (half of maximum power on the average good vacuum cleaner) and clean all holes, grilles on this power setting or keep the vacuum cleaner 2" (5 cm) away from the laptop
4. Buy a can of pressurized CO<sub>2</sub> and blow gently all over the open laptop (be extra careful with the keyboard)
5. With the laptop closed, blow at full pressure in all of the holes of your laptop (be careful with the DVD drive)
6. Download the service manual for your laptop, dismantle it and use the CO<sub>2</sub> can to gently blow out each component you remove.

Much more difficult then all the above:

10. Reassemble the laptop.

### If you've got new hardware:

You should take a software approach to things:

(larger number = more difficult)

1. Install `thermald` and set it to `quiet`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install thermald
   sudo nano /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
   ```

   ensure `<Preference>Quiet</Preference>` is set and **not `<Preference>Quiet</Preference>`**
2. Install `indicator-cpufreq`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
   indicator-cpufreq
   ```

   The CPU frequency indicator shows you the current speed of your CPU and lets you control CPU speed, enable power-saving mode, enable high-performance mode, ...
3. Disable your GPU in the BIOS or for nVidia: open `nvidia-settings` and switch the GPU to Intel.

## ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try adjusting your power settings, specifically your maximum processor usage to reduce excessive heat build up. This is not something that can be accomplished with a single button click, but it is possible using some lightweight software. [THIS PAGE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706) explains step-by-step how to achieve this. It is a relatively lengthy article, so I won't re-type it, but it should provide you with enough information to assist you.

Comment: To be helpful you should also state **how** to accomplish those things.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide more information and linked resources.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...